# Recurring payments | every 1, 3, 6 or 12 months | sum total income by month in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple monthly support contracts with always the same payment per client and per month. Some clients pay every month, others pay every 3, 6 or 12 months. I know the starting month for every contract. And I would like to see what is my income for January, February, etc.

How can I calculate the income at the different months?

Here are three samples:

| Client | amount per month | starting month | pays every X months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client A | $29 | 1 (January) | 3 |
| client B | $39 | 3 (March) | 6 |
| client C | $49 | 10 (October) | 12 |

Income for January: $XXX

Income for February: $XXX
...

Comment: is there a limit to the number of months or are we to assume a rolling 12 month period. Please [edit] your question accordingly together with what you have tried so far and the results to save unnecessary repetition.

Answer (score 1):

First, replace starting months that are text strings like `1 (January)` with dates like `2023-01-01`:

| Client | Amount | Start date | Pays every X months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client A | $29 | **2023-01-01** | 3 |
| client B | $39 | **2023-03-01** | 6 |
| client C | $49 | **2023-10-01** | 12 |

You can then get a list of payments like this:

```
=lambda( 
  numMonths, amounts, startDates, periods, 
  query( 
    reduce( 
      { "month", "income" }, sequence(numMonths, 1, 0), 
      lambda( 
        result, monthOrdinal, 
        { 
          result; 
          map( 
            amounts, startDates, periods, 
            lambda( 
              amount, startDate, period, 
              { 
                edate(startDate, monthOrdinal), 
                amount * not(mod(monthOrdinal, period)) 
              } 
            ) 
          ) 
        } 
      ) 
    ), 
    "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 
     limit " & numMonths & " 
     format Col1 'MMM yyyy', sum(Col2) '$0' ", 1 
  ) 
)(
  24, 
  filter(B2:B, isnumber(C2:C)), 
  filter(C2:C, isnumber(C2:C)), 
  filter(D2:D, isnumber(C2:C)) 
)
```

...with these results:

| month | sum income |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 2023 | $29 |
| Feb 2023 | $0 |
| Mar 2023 | $39 |
| Apr 2023 | $29 |
| May 2023 | $0 |
| Jun 2023 | $0 |
| Jul 2023 | $29 |
| Aug 2023 | $0 |
| Sep 2023 | $39 |
| Oct 2023 | $78 |
| Nov 2023 | $0 |
| Dec 2023 | $0 |
| ... | ... |

To choose how far in the future the results extend, modify the `24` that signifies the number of months to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula, according to your proposed cells:

```
={Sequence(12),BYROW(SEQUENCE(12),LAMBDA(each,SUM(FILTER(B:B,MOD(C:C,D:D)=MOD(each,D:D)))))}
```

For this to work you should change your values in C to numbers, if you can't let me know!

Comment: I think this gives the correct results for the first 12 months with the sample data specified in the question. But it does not observe the start date correctly — try changing client 3's "pays every X months" to `2` to see the issue.